# Strange behavior of vim color inside screen with 256 colors

Tags: bash, vim, colors, terminal, gnu-screen

I was trying to make the syntax highlighting (with 256 colors) of `vim` work inside `screen`, which is running inside `gterm`.

It works quite fine in the beginning. What I mean by "in the beginning" is, after I start `screen`, and enter `vim`, the colors look fine, and there are really 256 colors.

But after a while (I don't know exactly how long) the colors automatically change back to an appearance as if there are only 8 (or 16?) colors.

For example, after this has already occurred, if I enter the command

```
hi Comment ctermfg=68
```

inside `vim`, the comments appear to be "pure" green; however, if I open another `vim` outside screen (in the same terminal), then with the same command the comments appear to be a "yellowish" green.

The following is my .screenrc settings related to color:

```
attrcolor b ".I"
defbce "on"
termcapinfo xterm 'Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm'
term xterm-256color
```

After running a python script to display all the colors, I find out that maybe this is a problem of screen itself, and has nothing to do with vim.

What I did is, inside the `screen` session with problems, this script gives 256 colors, but many of them are actually the same; however, when I start a new screen session with the same configuration, this script gives 256 colors which are distinct from each other.

Edit:

Last night I connected to my Linux computer (which is in my office and it is always on) with `putty`, then opened a `screen` session with multiple windows in it. The colors are correct last night. Then before I went to sleep I detached the `screen` session and closed `putty`.

Now in the morning when I attach that `screen` session in `putty` again, the colors crash: they appear as if there are only 8 colors.

The colors are fine outside `screen` (but still in `putty`).

Edit:

Three years later after I asked this question, today I saw a similar problem.  The problem is that `vim` can display 256 colors outside `screen`, and `screen` can display 256 colors with a test script, but `vim` can't display any color (can only display black and white) inside `screen`.  Just as a note to myself, here is the `.screenrc` file I am using

```
hardstatus alwayslastline "%{.bW}%-w%{.rW}%n %t%{-}%+w %=%{..G} %H %{..Y} %Y-%m-%d %c"
shell "bash"
startup_message off
vbell off
altscreen on
attrcolor b ".I"
defbce "on"
termcapinfo xterm* 'is=\E[r\E[m\E[2J\E[H\E[?7h\E[?1;4;6l'
termcapinfo xterm 'Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm'
term screen-256color
```

The solution to the problem is already mentioned in the accepted answer, namely, I need to include

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

in `.bashrc`.

Comment: Did you try your configuration with another terminal emulator? I tried your options with gnome-terminal and xterm. It work ok with both no matter how many sessions i opened.

Comment: Both screen and tmux [are known](http://superuser.com/questions/145475/terminal-proxy-or-screen-without-terminal-emulation) to spoil hues. If you don't need advanced screen features but only protection from accidental terminal closing you can use dtach. For all colors I saw hues are spoiled not much, so maybe you should instead change a terminal emulator.

Comment: Thanks for answering!
After having been waiting for almost one day, the problem finally reappears. But I still don't know what actually triggered this problem.

Comment: Last night I connected to my Linux computer (which is in my office and it is always on) with putty, then opened a screen session with multiple windows in it. The colors are correct last night. Then before I went to sleep I detached the screen session and closed putty.

Now when I attach that screen session in putty again, the colors crash: they appear as if their are only 8 colors.

Comment: Probably not the source of your problem, but setting `term xterm-256color` in .screenrc is wrong. It tells applications running in screen that they're running in xterm, when of course they're running inside screen. It should be set to `screen-256color`. Also, you can leave out the `termcapinfo` line if you set `TERM` to `xterm-256color` before invoking screen to tell it that 256 colours are available.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

### Short Answer

Set `TERM` to `xterm-256color` in your `.bashrc`, and put `term screen-256color` in your `.screenrc`.

### Long Answer

Here's why this breaks: gnome-terminal, screen, tmux, bash, putty and vim have *all* been written to intelligently handle 256 colors, but you need to set things up correctly at the earliest possible point.  Using `termcapinfo` in your `.screenrc` is actually a duct tape solution!

If your `TERM` is set correctly, it will signal to bash that you're in 256-color mode, which means it will play nice with screen being in 256-color mode as well.

So, in your `.bashrc`, `export TERM=xterm-256color`. [1]

In your `.screenrc`, use `screen-256color` for `TERM` instead of `xterm-256color`, and delete the rest of the cruft!

In your PuTTy configuration, use `putty-256color`.

You can download the termcap entry files and put them in `~/.terminfo/s` and `~/.terminfo/p`, if your box doesn't have them by default.

---

*Footnotes*

[1] Setting `TERM` to `xterm-256color` in your `.bashrc` can be a little presumptuous, especially if you use the same `.bashrc` on multiple machines.  I have found the following snippet to be fairly effective:

```bsh
case "$TERM" in
*-256color)
    alias ssh='TERM=${TERM%-256color} ssh'
    ;;
*)
    POTENTIAL_TERM=${TERM}-256color
    POTENTIAL_TERMINFO=${TERM:0:1}/$POTENTIAL_TERM

    # better to check $(toe -a | awk '{print $1}') maybe?
    BOX_TERMINFO_DIR=/usr/share/terminfo
    [[ -f $BOX_TERMINFO_DIR/$POTENTIAL_TERMINFO ]] && \
        export TERM=$POTENTIAL_TERM

    HOME_TERMINFO_DIR=$HOME/.terminfo
    [[ -f $HOME_TERMINFO_DIR/$POTENTIAL_TERMINFO ]] && \
        export TERM=$POTENTIAL_TERM
    ;;
esac
```

The `alias` of ssh is a defensive measure to prevent us from trying to open a 256-color terminal on a remote machine that doesn't necessarily support it.  The main block is the other half of the equation; it checks to see if the corresponding terminfo entry exists, and sets it if it does.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer!

Comment: You're welcome!  It represents many days spent sobbing uncontrollably while reading obtuse manpages.  Hopefully my suffering can shorten someone else's learning curve!

Comment: MANY thanks! Now there is only one annoying thing left in my love affair with vim: copy-pasting across servers.

Comment: I know this is old, but I still run into a problem. Once screen has started, I still need to run `export TERM=screen-256color`, otherwise `TERM` is stuck on `xterm-256color`, which `screen` doesn't like. Any idea why?

Comment: @NicolasMattia - Did you end up figuring this out? If not, maybe try putting something obviously broken in to your `.screenrc` to make sure it's being read.

Comment: I did both steps above (adding different TERM in both .bashrc and .screenrc) but when doing a 'echo $TERM' while in screen, I get 'xterm-256color'. Regardless, when I run a 'show256color' script that prints all 256 colors to my terminal while in screen it shows all 256 colors correctly. Before it would show a lot of greens and blues.

Comment: I had to set `TERM=screen-256color` instead of `TERM=xterm-256color` (which is suggested in this answer) in bash to get things working.

Answer (score 17):

Max has an excellent answer, but I actually had to **reinstall** screen with **`./configure --enable-colors256`** to ensure that the `config.h` file had `#define COLORS256 1` set, which was not the case by default on my machine. Then, I found that the other settings were not necessary so long as I ensured that my `TERM` was set to `xterm-256color`.

Comment: My only solution!

Comment: Thanks! I went through 3-4 threads before I found this. This turned out to the culprit in my case as well!

Comment: On MacOS, it suffices to install `screen` with HomeBrew: `brew install screen`. The default version does not support 256 colors.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of screen (v4.99.0), there is no need to use `term screen-256color` in your `.screenrc`. Even without this setting, the vim color inside and outside screen is exactly the same.

Note 1: I have tested this feature on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.4 and Ubuntu 16.04.

One can obtain the latest version of screen using
`git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/screen.git`.

Note 2: Unlike some of the previous versions, While [configuring](https://superuser.com/a/384179) this version of screen there is no need to use `--enable-colors256` option

Note 3: You need to have PAM support for this configuration to be successful. In ubuntu, you can use `sudo apt-get install libpam0g-dev`

Note 4: You will need `sudo` access on Ubuntu while doing `make install` as this step uses `chown`.

Comment: v.4.99 does not exist yet even now. I still face this problem with 4.08.00 (GNU) 05-Feb-20