# Vim colorschemes not working in GNU Screen even after setting .bashrc & .screenrc

Tags: vim, color-scheme, gnu-screen

I set my .screenrc and .bashrc files to the following answer here: [Strange behavior of vim color inside screen with 256 colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787734/strange-behavior-of-vim-color-inside-screen-with-256-colors)

But the colorschemes still do not work correctly in GNU Screen. If I'm out of GNU Screen the colorschemes are perfect, just in Screen.

Any other advice in fixing this issue would be appreciated!

Here are my bashrc, vimrc and screenrc files...

#### .bashrc file

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples
export TERM=xterm-256color
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

export NVM_DIR="/home/serge/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

#### .screenrc file

```
# An alternative hardstatus to display a bar at the bottom listing the
# windownames and highlighting the current windowname in blue. (This is only
# enabled if there is no hardstatus setting for your terminal)
# hardstatus on
# hardstatus alwayslastline
# hardstatus string "%{.bW}%-w%{.rW}%n %t%{-}%+w %=%{..G} %H %{..Y} %m/%d %C%a "
term screen-256color
```

#### .vimrc file

```
" use visual bell instead of beeping
"set vb
"   
" Basics {
set nocompatible " explicitly get out of vi-compatible mode

" i added this for colorshemes
"set term=xterm-256color

if $COLORTERM == 'gnome-terminal'
      set t_Co=256
  endif

syntax on
syntax enable
colorscheme twilight256
set background=dark "uncommented this & fixed the colorscheme issue


"let g:solarized_termcolors=256 " Added this for solarized

" General {
filetype plugin indent on " load filetype plugins/indent settings
set autochdir " always switch to the current file directory 
set backspace=indent,eol,start " make backspace a more flexible
set fileformats=unix,dos,mac " support all three, in this order
set iskeyword+=_,$,@,%,# " none of these are word dividers
set mouse=a " use mouse everywhere
set whichwrap=b,s,h,l,<,>,~,[,] " everything wraps
set wildmenu " turn on command line completion wild style

" Vim UI {
set laststatus=2 " always show the status line
set linespace=0 " don't insert any extra pixel lines betweens rows
set matchtime=5 " how many tenths of a second to blink matching brackets for
set novisualbell " don't blink
set number " turn on line numbers
set ruler " Always show current positions along the bottom
set showcmd " show the command being typed
set showmatch " show matching brackets
set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w[%L][%{&ff}]%y[%p%%][%04l,%04v]
nnoremap <C-N> :next<Enter> " this replaces :next, when opening multiple files
nnoremap <C-P> :prev<Enter> " this replaces :prev, when opening multiple files
set confirm

" Text Formatting/Layout {
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4 " not sure what this does?
set smarttab autoindent
set softtabstop=4 " when hitting tab or backspace, how many spaces 


" paste mode - this will avoid unexpected effects when you
" cut or copy some text from one window and paste it in Vim.
set pastetoggle=<F2>

" The 3 commands below are an experiment
" save file (ctrl-s)
"   :map <C-s> :w<cr>
" copy selected text (ctrl-c)
"   :vmap <C-c> y
" Paste clipboard contents (ctrl-v)
"   :imap <C-p> <esc>P
  " Press i to enter insert mode, and ii to exit. 
:imap jj <Esc>
:inoremap <C-S> <C-O>:w<CR>


" Filetype-Dependent Settings
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on

set modifiable

" Pathogen related
execute pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

*** EDIT**: Okay, I did something to the vimrc file (I had the 'set background=dark' commented out :/ ) That fixed the syntax highlighting.

*But now* terminal's background color bleeds into Vim’s. Here is a screenshot of the two:
https://s24.postimg.org/i81kjz1cl/Screenshot_from_2017-06-04_18_47_55.png

This is what the colorscheme *should* look like in gnu screen instead:
https://s7.postimg.org/47fo5qd97/image.png

***Solution:**
I found that the following code needed to be added to my .vimrc file. This fixed the background issue. I was led to the solution from this URL, https://stackoverflow.com/a/15279464/8110853 comment. Breifly, it looks like the  t_ut option in Vim only "uses the current background color" if the value is a non-empty string, which it is in xterm-256color but not under screen-256color. The solution is therefore to "clear Vim’s t_ut value if Vim happens to be running inside *any* 256-color terminal". The following codes, placed inside .vimrc does this. I put it at the end of the end of file.

`if &term =~ '256color'
  " disable Background Color Erase (BCE) so that color schemes
  " render properly when inside 256-color GNU screen.
  set t_ut=
endif`

Comment: Did you rebuild screen with `./configure --enable-colors256` as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16451794 ?

Comment: No, but someone suggested that there’s probably some other reason you’re I'm not getting 256 colours as screen is built with --enable-colors256 in Debian and Ubuntu: https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/screen.git/tree/debian/rules

Comment: user8110853, Good news! I think you may convert your last edit into answer (with some more details, citing the orginal source). There is nonzero probability it will be helpful for somebody.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit it to make it more useful for others to find. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**: Extracted the solution from question as an answer so that it's easier to spot. After struggling for days this worked for me and I nearly missed the solution as it was not an answer.

---

I found that the following code needed to be added to my `.vimrc` file. This fixed the background issue. I was led to the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15279464). Breifly, it looks like the `t_ut` option in Vim only "uses the current background color" if the value is a non-empty string, which it is in `xterm-256color` but not under `screen-256color`. The solution is therefore to "clear Vim’s t_ut value if Vim happens to be running inside any 256-color terminal". The following code in `.vimrc` does this. I put it at the end of the end of file.

```
if &term =~ '256color'
  " disable Background Color Erase (BCE) so that color schemes
  " render properly when inside 256-color GNU screen.
  set t_ut=
endif
```